# How to download a specific version of ASP.NET MVC 5 source code

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm looking for ASP.NET MVC 5.0 RTM source code. I've tried to download this from http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/ but it seems to have only the most recent version 5.1.1 RTM. I've tried with no success to download for a specific tag or branch. In Source Code tab, in field "Browsing Changes in" the only options are "master" or "v3-rtm".

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Then I guess the developer didn't try to take the pain to write the code for the previous versions...

Comment: I don´t see your point.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[As per their wiki:](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Repository%20Tags%20and%20Version%20Numbers)

MVC 5.2.3 RTM = v3.2.3 (commit 0e974218e12a)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0e974218e12a

MVC 5.2.2 RTM = v3.2.2 (commit 66298100f4e3)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66298100f4e3

MVC 5.1.3 RTM = v3.1.3 (commit 0150245a9e34)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0150245a9e34

MVC 5.1.1 RTM = v3.1.1 (commit 54866f0d3262)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54866f0d3262

MVC 5.0 RTM = v3.0 (commit 39391d3a64d7)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/39391d3a64d7

MVC 4.0 RTM = v2.0 (commit 89b9166ca722)
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89b9166ca722

Comment: What kind of black magic did you use to figure that out? How would I know what the changeset is for v5.2? Thanks.

Comment: Seriously what's the naming convention?  I need to know how to map from future MVC versions numbers to these abitrary internal ones?

Comment: Second, how did you figure this out?

Comment: Isn´t it something obivious? See the realation between the repository tag and the MVC version? MVC 5.2.2 = tag v3.2.2, MVC 5.1.3 = tag v3.1.3. I have no idea why the Asp.net team have used this notation.

Comment: @Jacob, there are not such black magic, you can see my answer.

Comment: Looks like they added a list of the various MVC versions and how they map to branches and tags: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Repository%20Tags%20and%20Version%20Numbers No commit links, but better than nothing, and in concert with the answers here should be enough.

Comment: @Joseph I looked at your answer but you are not explaining how to figure out that a tag named "v3.2.3" equals MVC 5.2.3.0?

Comment: When I search for asp.net MVC source code. I always reach asp.net CORE source code. What version of asp.net is considered the classic MVC that comes with .net 4.5 . Are all of the above asp.net MVC or is it considered 'CORE'  from a certain version.  Core of course being the rewritten asp.net MVC.

Answer (score 1):

In general way, if you have already cloned the repository. You can use the `Git` commands:

```
git show-ref --tags
```

Your will see something like:

```
89b9166ca72279fcb62bff67c6224993371ed765 refs/tags/v2.0
a1b7c04f72277e6dfc459d8d6948260d26ccc6c9 refs/tags/v2.0-rc
d4dab6e6c0b181ee56593a3a514faab7f407e1f2 refs/tags/v2.0.1
f276aa28c436c598e3c2a8e09d052e2b17630ab0 refs/tags/v2.0.2
75b5e7ea58d2a120242ff0d840600e33e9b65882 refs/tags/v2.0.3
26665357e13c050d298310e0f5c7925af32a66cd refs/tags/v2.0.4
1b78397f32fc13ea321647b5039755df4be58558 refs/tags/v2.1
235544cf12a25d2fd072c1eafec4c681c9d6068e refs/tags/v2.1-beta
f079d76e57b557d0215dbbaf5d398f64a74ebf90 refs/tags/v2.1-rc
39391d3a64d71ae735f7620ae082aea5f05cb0e0 refs/tags/v3.0
...
```

or

```
git tag -n
```

And all tags with their comments will be promped:

```
fbv1.0          Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook v1.0
fbv1.1          Upgrade ODataLib version from 6.7.0 to 6.8.0
fbv1.1-beta     Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook 1.1.0 Beta
odata-v5.3      Update Microsoft.AspNet.Facebook version.
v2.0            Added copyright statements to files lacking it.
...
```

Select the version to download by the tag, and executed the `git rev-parse` command to get the id of the commit: For example:

```
> git rev-parse --short=12 v3.2.3
> 0e974218e12a                   //This is the first 12 characters of SHA commit.
```

With the first 12 characters of the SHA of the commit you can now build the url. For example:

**Version 3.2.2** = https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/66298100f4e3
**Version 3.2.3** = https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0e974218e12a
...

or just call `git checkout` command:

```
git checkout v3.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful when looking for sources of concrete MVC/WebAPI/Web Pages version:
https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20from%20Source

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the CodePlex repo, with all history, was migrated to GitHub!

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack

They even have a milestone for ASP.Net MVC 5.2.4, although it seems somewhat dead:

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/milestone/1

The [Releases tab](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/releases) contains the appropriate versions [as per @outlookrperson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21932540/70345) (basically, add 2 to the major version in the tag, e.g. tag 3.2.3 = MVC 5.2.3).