# Significant server side time spent in SendResponse segment of DOTNET category

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.5, newrelic

Our New Relic apm transaction reporting shows one transaction (an MVC controller method returning an ActionResult) spending approximately 90-95% of its time a segment called SendResponse.

This is a framework category, and so I can't get any more information.

I would like to understand what is exactly happening under the hood here, but I cant find anything on Google for dotnet sendresponse which is what New Relic report it as, so I'm not sure where to look or what perfmon counters might be useful.

Other transactions show less time (generally 40-50%) spent here, so its clearly something about this one.

Comment: "I would like to understand what is exactly happening under the hood here" - Perhaps you could look at [the source code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21932540/181087)?

Comment: Ok - I'll look at that. Do you know which class SendResponse is a member of (assuming that it is one). Googling "aspnet mvc sendresponse" shows this question as the first result...